# sourcing in bash doesn't mimic sourcing in tcsh

Tags: bash, colors, echo, xterm, tcsh

The file below, which I've called /tmp/ltSortedList, when sourced in tcsh, outputs lines in different colors:

```
echo "\033[0;34m  R:0         2020  12  10  18:53  regularFile "\\e[0m
echo "\033[0;34m  R:32325978  2020  12  10  17:10  G670_UserGuide_Long.pdf "\\e[0m
echo "\033[0;31m  S:13        2020  12  09  18:49  /tmp/linkTarget "\\e[0m
```

But when I source it from bash (or use .) the coloring doesn't work (see figure).   Presumably it has something to do with the control codes.[image]

Could somebody please explain how to get the same result in bash as I get in tcsh?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that in both `tcsh` and `bash` you're getting a built-in implementation of `echo`; `tcsh`'s implementation is interpreting the escape sequences and `bash`'s is not.

Try this:

```
/bin/echo -e "\033[0;34m  R:0         2020  12  10  18:53  regularFile "\\e[0m
/bin/echo -e "\033[0;34m  R:32325978  2020  12  10  17:10  G670_UserGuide_Long.pdf "\\e[0m
/bin/echo -e "\033[0;31m  S:13        2020  12  09  18:49  /tmp/linkTarget "\\e[0m
```

That will make sure you use the `/bin/echo` binary.  The `-e` flag will cause `/bin/echo` to interpret the escape characters.

Comment: On a 100% POSIX platform, `-e` is echoed itself and escape sequences are always expanded. This is e.g. how bas is compiled in Solaris and MacOS

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to tcsh. In bash, echo is builtin, `/bin/echo` is not, but the crucial point is the `-e`. Both echo and `/bin/echo` will do the color changing with it, without it will not.

Comment: Except if he's sourcing the same file in both shells, `tcsh`'s builtin `echo` might _not_ support `-e`.  Explicitly using `/bin/echo` makes sure to use the same tool with the same behavior across both shells.